# div focusout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery 1.9.1. i need to catch focusout event when click outside of div. I'm using id for do this. here is my code,

HTML :

```
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
```

script:

```
 $('#mydiv').focusout(function (){
        $(".num_C").removeClass('change_bg');
      });
```

this focusout not working as i expected. how to catch this event. i need remove `.num_C` class when click outside of `#mydiv`. anyone got this. can i give solution for do this ?

Comment: [`<div>` cannot be focused, use `mouseleave`.](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/opnbc0sr/)

Comment: then how i do this. is there any solution ?

Comment: what do you mean by focus out of a div?

Comment: div element @ArunPJohny i need to catch when click outside of this elemant #mydiv

Comment: give the div a tabindex value > 0 - but this will only work if the div has focus, then loses focus

Comment: solution need to work with IE10 or latest.

Comment: @Tushar thanks your solution. but i need click event do this not `mouseleave`. when click outside of this div

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Comment: Using "onblur" will be a better option

Comment: thanks it's work @Tushar :)